# Extract value of the first non-random column

Tags: r

In my dataset, I have 10 columns filled with CR, II and RAND. I want to create another 2 columns, one column extracts the value of the first block that does not have "RAND" as its value, the other column tracks this block number. For example, a certain ID may have "RAND" in block_1 and block_2, and "II" in block_3, I want the first new column to have value "II" and the second new column to have value "3". How can I achieve this?

Below is an example dataframe.

```
set.seed(2288)
dff<-data.frame(replicate(10,sample(c("II", "RAND","CR"),10,rep=TRUE)))

myFun<- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}

dff$ID<-myFun(10)
dff<-dff[,c(11, 1:10)]
dff[2:11] <- sapply(dff[2:11],as.factor)

dff<-data.table::setnames(dff, old = c('X1','X2','X3','X4', 'X5','X6','X7','X8','X9','X10'), new = c('block_1','block_2','block_3','block_4', 'block_5','block_6','block_7','block_8','block_9','block_10'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
func <- function(..., val = "0") {
  dat <- unlist(list(...))
  ind <- which.max(dat != val)
  list(dat[[ind]], ind)
}
setNames(
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, do.call(Map, c(list(f=func), dff[,-1]))),
  c("val", "ind"))
#    val ind
# 2    2   1
# 1    1   1
# 11   1   1
# 21   2   1
# 0    1   2
# 12   1   1
# 01   1   2
# 02   2   3
# 22   2   1
# 03   2   4
```

(That can be `cbind`ed to the data.)

Alternatively, find the indices first, then retrieve the values second. Perhaps a cleaner approach?

```r
do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN=func), dff[,-1]))
# 2.block_1 1.block_1 1.block_1 2.block_1 0.block_2 1.block_1 0.block_2 0.block_3 2.block_1 0.block_4 
#         1         1         1         1         2         1         2         3         1         4 
dff$ind <- do.call(mapply, c(list(FUN=func), dff[,-1]))
dff$val <- dff[,-1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(dff)), dff$ind)]
dff
#            ID block_1 block_2 block_3 block_4 block_5 block_6 block_7 block_8 block_9 block_10 ind val
# 1  CIKJH1554S       2       1       0       0       2       2       1       2       1        1   1   2
# 2  URADX4138B       1       1       2       1       1       1       2       0       0        2   1   1
# 3  BWYCA9574K       1       0       1       1       2       1       2       1       1        1   1   1
# 4  FKBFM4773W       2       0       0       1       1       1       2       1       0        1   1   2
# 5  LTTTI7549S       0       1       0       1       1       0       2       2       1        2   2   1
# 6  OJDSI8401L       1       1       1       2       2       0       0       1       0        0   1   1
# 7  IAUKO4799A       0       1       0       1       1       1       1       2       0        2   2   1
# 8  WBJPE0696J       0       0       2       0       0       1       0       0       0        2   3   2
# 9  FNFQC9244G       2       1       0       2       1       0       2       1       2        1   1   2
# 10 WQTRB4780S       0       0       0       2       1       2       2       0       2        2   4   2
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but the returned columns are all from block_1 and "ind" value was always 1. I don't know if it matters to say that 0:2 are nominal values which cannot be ordered.

Comment: Not sure what to say ... it works with the sample data, I don't understand what is different about your real data.

Comment: The updated sample data *still* does not return all 1s. My first code block returns `structure(list(val = c("CR", "CR", "II", "CR", "II", "CR", "II", "II", "CR", "II"), ind = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))`. (The only change to my function was to change `val="RAND"`.)

Comment: Sorry, I put the wrong value for val the first time..

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized option using `max.col` :

```
block_cols <- grep('block', names(dff))
dff$col2 <- max.col(dff[block_cols] != 'RAND', ties.method = 'first')
dff$col1 <- dff[block_cols][cbind(1:nrow(dff), dff$col2)]
dff

#           ID block_1 block_2 block_3 block_4 block_5 block_6 block_7 block_8 block_9 block_10 col1 col2
#1  CIKJH1554S      CR    RAND      II      II      CR      CR    RAND      CR    RAND     RAND   CR    1
#2  URADX4138B    RAND    RAND      CR    RAND    RAND    RAND      CR      II      II       CR   CR    3
#3  BWYCA9574K    RAND      II    RAND    RAND      CR    RAND      CR    RAND    RAND     RAND   II    2
#4  FKBFM4773W      CR      II      II    RAND    RAND    RAND      CR    RAND      II     RAND   CR    1
#5  LTTTI7549S      II    RAND      II    RAND    RAND      II      CR      CR    RAND       CR   II    1
#6  OJDSI8401L    RAND    RAND    RAND      CR      CR      II      II    RAND      II       II   CR    4
#7  IAUKO4799A      II    RAND      II    RAND    RAND    RAND    RAND      CR      II       CR   II    1
#8  WBJPE0696J      II      II      CR      II      II    RAND      II      II      II       CR   II    1
#9  FNFQC9244G      CR    RAND      II      CR    RAND      II      CR    RAND      CR     RAND   CR    1
#10 WQTRB4780S      II      II      II      CR    RAND      CR      CR      II      CR       CR   II    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Note the `-1` column index when you run the checker function - it keeps your `id` column out of the equation. If your ids are actually rownames then you should remove the `-1`.

```
checker <- function(row){
  # Find the first row (minimum index) with a value
  # greater than zero.
  first_nonzero_col <- min(which(row > 0))
  
  # Use the index to get the value from the row and
  # coerce to factor at the same time.
  first_nonzero_val <- as.factor(row[first_nonzero_col][[1]])
  
  # Return a pretty data.frame.
  data.frame("value" = first_nonzero_val,
             "block" = first_nonzero_col)
}

# Make new columns to put the values in.
dff$value <- NA
dff$block <- NA

# Iterate over the rows and write values to the new columns.
for(i in 1:dim(dff)[1]){
  temp <- checker(dff[i,-1])
  dff$value[i] <- temp[1]
  dff$block[i] <- temp[2]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidy approach (I think this is the output you wanted?):

```
df2 <- dff %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(value >0) %>% 
  summarise(location = name[which(value>0) == TRUE],
            value = value[which(value>0) == TRUE])

dff <- left_join(dff, df2, by = "ID")
```